# What's the Lie group generated only by dilation and Poincaré symmetry?

Tags: group-theory, conformal-field-theory, poincare-symmetry, scale-invariance

Given space $\mathbb{R}^{1,d-1}$($d\ge3$), the total [conformal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_symmetry) is $SO(d,2)$ generated by $1$-dilation, $d$-translation, $d$-special conformal, $d(d-1)/2$-Lorentz transformation.

But we know generators of Poincare symmetry and dilation are closed, so form a Lie subalgebra of Lie algebra $so(d,2)$. So what's the Lie group corresponding to Lie algebra generated only by Poincare symmetry and dilation? Is it a classical Lie group or (semi-)direct product of classical Lie group or others?

The only nontrivial commutator between dilation and Poincare symmetry is 
$$[D,P_\mu]=iP_\mu$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sometimes called the Weyl Group
$$W(1,d-1)\sim\mathbb R \ltimes\mathrm{ISO}(1,d-1)$$

The only references I've been able to find in a quick google search are *At the Frontier of Spacetime: Scalar-Tensor Theory, Bells Inequality, Machs Principle...*, section 4.1.4, and *Theoretical and Observational Cosmology*, section 5.2. They are both on Google Books.

Indeed, dilatations are also called Weyl transformations. Unfortunately, this terminology is not universally accepted. I don't know what is the name of this group in the mathematical literature, nor whether it has been studied in detail. It doesn't seem *that* interesting on its own, but who am I to say.

Comment: I think by Weyl transformations one usually means the more general transformations, when one rescales the metric by a scalar function. (In this case these are not coordinate transformations, but just the "manual" transformations of the metric.)